# Implementing a dictionary using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to make an online [German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language) to [Hindi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi) dictionary. There are dictionary implementations using PHP and MySQL. But I thought if it is possible to make a dictionary using HTML and Javascript. The words in the dictionary will be stored as JSON. Some demos of Javascript showed that it could do complex graphics and calcultions jobs such as online game emulators etc.

1. In that case is it possible to implement a dictionary ?
2. Also will it be possible in JavaScript to do a lookup on the alphabets of Hindi other than the English alphabet ?
3. How will be the performance ? Will it be slow ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  However, I'm pretty sure nobody here will code it for you if that's what you mean.

Comment: BTW, `dictionary` (in programming) as you tagged is different than a language dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. If you're writing it in **only** JavaScript, without server stored data, the performance will be bad (at least on initial loading). JS is a client-side language, therefore all the data (words) will have to be downloaded by the browser. From there it depends on your code performance and the client's computer.